Buying tickets online for Heiva I Tahiti 2024 (French Polynesia)
I want to see some events for the Heiva I Tahiti this year. I won't be in Tahiti until July, so would like to buy tickets online.
However, the web site of the event organizer (Maison de la Culture) has no mention of buying tickets online.
Where can I buy tickets online for the Heiva I Tahiti?

Have you tried contacting them?  https://tahititourisme.pf/en-pf/events-tickets/all-the-events/heiva-i-tahiti-papeete-en-en-pf-4590283/ has a contact link

Have you been able to see if they sold tickets online in previous years? I have seen a lack of sales options till the actual sales open in other occasions but do not know anything about this event.

After some searching I found that you can buy online tickets through
https://billetterie.maisondelaculture.pf/index.php?page=events
